# Recommanded step for Apache and mysql Performance tuning

Tags: apache2, mysql, performance, lamp

I googling lots of sites and forums to solve issue but i didn't get result as my expectation.

I installed successfully Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on **ProLiant DL360** hardware with LAMP environment.

Hardware Detail

```
CPU - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Memory - 64 GB (2133 MHz)
HDD - 1.5 TB LVM Configured 15K
```

I want to tune apache and mysql for best performance. Right now I tuned by help of some forum but still we can't get proper speed and performance.

Its a kind request to reply with proper configuration tips and help.

Help would be really appreciated.

Awaiting response. 
Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to load the whole database into a RAM disk, if it fits. First, create a disk in memory:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=350M tmpfs /var/tmp/ramdisk
```

Adjust size as needed.
Then move the database to this disk:

```
rsync -av /var/lib/mysql/* /var/tmp/ramdisk/
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmp/ramdisk
```

Then start the database server. In `my.cnf` you point the server to the RAM disk instead of the default location.

You may want to periodically dump the database back to the hard disk, in case a power loss wipes all memory.  And after shutdown of the MySQL server, the database needs to be copied back to the disk once again.